# Vim Vundle PluginInstall fails because of "command not found"

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, vundle

When I run `:PluginInstall` on Vim, I get the following log output:

```
[2020-07-21 13:50:38] Plugin URI change detected for Plugin Vundle.vim
[2020-07-21 13:50:38] >  Plugin Vundle.vim old URI: zsh:1: command not found: git
[2020-07-21 13:50:38] >  Plugin Vundle.vim new URI: https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git
[2020-07-21 13:50:39] 
[2020-07-21 13:50:39] Plugin VundleVim/Vundle.vim
[2020-07-21 13:50:39] $ cd '/Users/michael/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim' && git remote set-url origin 'https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git' && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/HEAD && git submodule update --init --recursive
[2020-07-21 13:50:39] > zsh:1: command not found: git
[2020-07-21 13:50:39] > 
[2020-07-21 13:50:40] 
[2020-07-21 13:50:40] Helptags:
[2020-07-21 13:50:40] :helptags /Users/michael/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/doc
[2020-07-21 13:50:40] Helptags: 1 plugins processed
```

I've tried the following:

1. Run rm -rf .vim and rm .vimrc and rm .viminfo;
2. Run brew uninstall macvim;
3. Make sure my .zshrc contains `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`;
4. Copy and paste the .vimrc from the [Vundle README](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start);
5. Open vim and run :PluginInstall

Yesterday, I installed the following:

- Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
- Plugin 'dense-analysis/ale'
- Plugin 'preservim/nerdtree'
- Plugin 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
- Plugin 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
- Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
- Plugin 'wakatime/vim-wakatime'
- Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'

I installed them all according to the methods in their respective GitHub READMEs; not necessarily Vundle. Everything was working fine yesterday. I tried uninstalling Ale today and all Hell broke loose.

BTW, I did not have `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` or `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"` in .zshrc yesterday.  I added sbin first-thing today as a result of a `brew doctor` warning.  I uncommented the bin line just for kicks.  Neither had any effect on Vim.

Comment: "*zsh:1: command not found: git*" Do you have `git` installed and in the `$PATH`?

Comment: Yes, Git is installed

Comment: I don’t have anything in .zshrc to put it in the path though.

Comment: I rolled my system back a couple days to before I installed Vundle, and so I won't be able to do any more troubleshooting on the issue if anyone else comes upon this problem.  I don't know what the problem was.